# Persisting spatial data from pyspark df/rdd to postgis?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am new to pyspark. I have following data in RDD:

```
Row( id=u'00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000',  
the_geom={ u'minlt':
{u'N': u'41.48951093274956'},  
u'minln': {u'N':u'-90.49874687116228'},  
u'maxln': {u'N': u'-90.49282120016213'}, 
u'maxlt': {u'N': u'41.49186482074968'}} 
)
```

How do I make a spatial query and persist it to postgis?

Comment: I currently face a similar problem with oracle. First try to normalize the record i.e. make sure no arrays are used. Try to have it all in separate columns. Then load the jdbc driver and simply invoke `spark.write.jdbc(someConfiguration)`. Try first to load into a regular non spatial table.

Comment: What do you mean by make a spatial query? Convert those values into a bounding box, a polygon, or something else?

Comment: @Barça: Convert it to polygon and persist it to potgis

Comment: @GeorgHeiler I cannot directly commit spatial data with > spark.write.jdbc(someConfiguration)

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? first try it with a dummy data frame of e.g. Int and string like https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/88ee8709b6b01b593235efdc7693b2ab when this works you can upload your dataset in a regular non spatial table (where value types are int/string/... i.e. basic types) Then you only need to figure out how to get it into a spatial table. But that should be rather easy from there on.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler  really? It did not occur to me. Thank you very much. btw, the questions says Persisting "spatial data".

Comment: Sure. But the first step is to get the basic connection up and running. Then you can go on from there. The question will when be if the types of spark (i.e. probably basic types like int for x,y) will be *harmonized* automatically with the db.

Answer (score 1):

i haven't figured out how to get either the RDD or DF to write with the built-in functions into PostGIS. It seems the data types are not supported in PySpark (though they might be in Spark so if you are using scala it should work).

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11526
https://github.com/harsha2010/magellan/issues/31

What you can do is create your own function which batch-inserts rows.

something like the following:

```
import psycopg2

class PostgresUploader:

    def __init__(self):
        # Do some initial configurations...

    # Assuming you have POINT(x,y,z) but you can do it for 2D as well
    def lst2pgpoint(self, alist):
        return "POINT({x},{y},{z})"\
            .format(x=alist[0], y=alist[1], z=alist[2])

    # Binarize the query
    def mogrify(self, lines):
        with self.connect() as connection:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                args_list = b','.join(cursor.mogrify("(%s)",
                    (self.lst2pgpoint(x))) for x in lines)
        return args_list

    # Submit a batch insert for a given set of records (partition)
    def insert(self, recs):
        args_str = self.mogrify(recs)
        query = b"INSERT INTO table VALUES " + \
                args_str + b" ON CONFLICT (location) DO NOTHING"
        self.execute(query)

    # Establish connection and execute query
    def execute(self, sql, params=None):
        with self.connect() as connection:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                if params is None:
                    cursor.execute(sql)
                else:
                    cursor.execute(sql, params)
                cursor.close()
```

Then you would instantiate the class and let the RDD take its course:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(...) # Create an RDD of xyz triplets
pg_uploader = PostgresUploader()
# do whatever other configs on pg_uploader
rdd \
    .repartition(num_partitions) \
    .foreachPartition(pg_uploader.insert)
```